# Исключить некоторые тэги из выборки DOM

Tags: javascript

Привет ребята, понадобилось мне сделать подсветку слов при поиске, для этого взял [скрипт вот этого парня](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm), работает он как нужно - все нормально.. но он ищет по всему документу (доставая из document.body.innerHTML) , а мне нужно искать везде кроме двух div'ов. У кого-то есть идеи как можно исключить их из поиска?

Comment: пробовал, но скрипт работает так что при выделении перерисовывает всю страницу, и если туда (в var bodyText) не включить некоторые дивы, то после выделения их не станет =(
да и вообще всё что не включить в bodyText - пропадёт после выделения

Comment: да, уже разобрался, спасибо)

заметил что всегда легче разобрать проблему когда детально описываешь ее гдето, вот и пишу здесь ))

Comment: @Denis Masster, может потрудитесь тогда оформить чётко вопрос и найденное решение здесь? Если, конечно, время есть.

Comment: да без проблем)вечерком распишу

Spectre, продублируйте свой комментарий в ответ, зачту как правильный ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в коде есть такая строка:

```
var bodyText = document.body.innerHTML;
```

рекомендую искать не по всему `body`, а только в пределах определённого "контейнера", в который не входит те div'ы которые не стоит включать в поиск

**UPD:**

```
document.body.innerHTML = bodyText;
```

а вот здесь использоть `innerHTML` вашего контейнера

Answer (score 0):

Решение заключается в том что скрипт брал весь документ, обрабатывал его и потом уже обработанный кусок документа возвращал обратно в документ.

Мне же нужно было делать это для всего документа кроме двух дивов, в моем случае это выглядело как:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="needThis"></div>
 <div id="do_not_touch_this"></div>
 <div id="and_this"></div>
</div>
```

Соответсвенно перед обработкой do_not_touch_this и and_this копируем в переменные, а needThis передаем на обработку скрипту. По завершению обработки очищаем container, вставляем needThis и возвращаем из переменных do_not_touch_this и and_this.